# Can't use NSLocalizableString - iOS app

Tags: ios, swift

I have to implement in 3 languages my iOS app, but since the content will be managed by a web-admin, I can't use `NSLocalizable`. How should I proceed and what would be the best practices.

One of our options is to make a class for the UI strings, we would refer to them with id's, and this class would return the string based on the current language.

We're just not sure this is the best way. Thank you.

Comment: So the app statically knows the display but it's dependent upon some value returned from the server (not injected into the text, a control value)? Show an example

Comment: Example: I have to show a list of conditions in a table view. But the text in the cells is dependent on the current language. But i can't use localizable strings because i must retrieve it from the server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're retrieving the values for display in specific languages from the server then you should be passing the language to the server (or having the server return identifiers that you can use as keys to `NSLocalizableStrings`). You should get the language to pass with `preferredLanguages` from `NSLocale` or `localeIdentifier` from the `currentLocale`.

Comment: I can't do that. Because the client will be adding content in the web-admin page.

Comment: You need to teach your system about the languages throughout or it's impossible...